# Sitecore. Disable a pipeline's processor

Tags: sitecore, pipeline

I need to patch Sitecore's pipeline to disable one of the processors.
Can I do that, or should I remove and implement whole pipeline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing like `disabling` processor in Sitecore out of the box.

What you can do, you can create a patch config which will remove that processor. But you need to be aware that this processor will never be executed unless you change the configuration again and application is restarted.

Below is example how to remove `RunQueries` processor from the `contentSearch.queryWarmup` pipeline:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
  <pipelines>
    <contentSearch.queryWarmup>
        <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.QueryWarmups.RunQueries, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <patch:delete />
        </processor>
    </contentSearch.queryWarmup>
  </pipelines>
</sitecore>
```

---

**IMPORTANT:**

Remember that Sitecore parses all the config files alphabetically, and then subfolders (alphabetically again). So your patch file must be added "after" the original config which adds the processor. You may want to put all your patches e.g. in `App_Config/ZZ.Custom/my.patch.config`.

Comment: this is exactly what I need. Do you have any examples of processor removing? If so, could you update your answer with that, please?

Comment: Thanks a lot for example and explanations.